# How to have avbin.dll in a local directory (not C:\Windows\System) (for pyglet 1.2.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyglet

Using pyglet 1.2.4, I am using avbin.dll to allow me to play audio and all sources say it needs to go into C:\Windows\System. This works, but I would like to put in in a local folder, so that when it is downloaded, the user does not need to explicitly put it there.

How can I make it so that I specify the directory of avbin.dll/have in the same folder as the code?

Here, avbin.dll is in the folder with the code, but I can't find how they did it.
https://github.com/surajsinghbisht054/Python-Media-Player/tree/master/Python%20Media%20Player%20Version%200.0.1/Tools
I tried going through it but I didn't find anything

I tried

```py
pyglet.options["search_local_libs"]
```

but it was already set to true.

I also added it to the path variable, but this didn't change anything.

The intention was to be able to play audio files.

Additionally:
Using pyglet 1.4, I tried using `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-pyglet`, which works great, except that  `pyglet.app.run()` is required to stop the first part of the track playing on repeat, but its mainloop interferes with tkinter's and I can't seem to get either working in threads, which is why I reverted back to 1.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solve by just creating an installer using NSIS [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System ] .It is easy to create an installer using NSIS just for reference i will show you !

```
 !include LogicLib.nsh
 !include x64.nsh
   # define installer name
   OutFile "mp3player_installer.exe"

;set the default install directoy to programfilesx86
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES32

 Section 
   ;checking system architechure 
   ;if 64bit set the installation path to SysWOW64 else to system32
   ${If} ${RunningX64} 
     SetOutPath "$WINDIR\SysWOW64\"
     File avbin.dll
   ${Else}
     SetOutPath "$WINDIR\System32\"
     File avbin.dll
   ${EndIf}
 SectionEnd

 Section
   ;set the output path to programfilesx86/Application dir
   SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\Mp3Player\"
   ;the file need to copy ref with File Attribute you can set multiple file refs here
    File Application.py
   ;just create an uninstaller 
    WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Mp3Player\uninstall.exe"
 SectionEnd

 Section "Uninstall"
  # Always delete uninstaller first
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Mp3Player\uninstaller.exe"

  # now delete installed file
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Mp3Player\Application.py"
  Delete "$WINDIR\SysWOW64\avbin.dll"
SectionEnd
```

You can install NSIS Application and just create an installer.nsi file and copy this code and compile the script by just right click the installer.nsi file and select compile with NSIS Script the result will generate an installer for you !

Answer (score 1):

If you put the avbin dll in your folder (or install it globally using the installer), then write:

after the import of pyglet, like this:

```
 import pyglet
 pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')
 pyglet.have_avbin=True
```

It will load and use avbin

Note : Some times dll not found error occurred in that case copy paste avbin.dll [if you are using 32 bit python ] to windows->SysWOW64 dir.

Comment: On an application using avbin, how can I reliably use it on 32-bit? Is the only solution to do a try-except and if it fails, ask the user to put it there?